# Creating a PDF file containing a clickable file attachment

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to revive some old code that creates a PDF file directly (not using any API). It is pretty simple, just some plain text, followed by one or more attachments. I'm trying to make it so when a reader clicks on the attachment name, Windows will open the corresponding application using that file.

I'm certain that this used to work, however now it does not.  When hovering over the attachment name, the cursor turns to a hand, and clicking causes the area to highlight, but the application does not start - nothing happens.

I was thinking the problem is enhanced security in Adobe Reader, but that does not seem to be true. I have turned off all security, and the checkbox "Allow opening of non-PDF file attachments with external applications" is enabled.

So is my PDF formatting code incorrect now? Below is the entirety of a very simple file. The attachment should be located in c:\temp2\pdf\PDF Attachments\ewsmeet.txt. If someone could look at this and tell me what the problem is, I would very much appreciate it.

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F2
/BaseFont /Courier-Bold
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F3
/BaseFont /Times-Roman
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text]
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Length 184 >>
stream
BT
/F1 12 Tf
10 750 Td
14 TL
(This is dummy text.) '
/F3 12 Tf
() '
/F1 12 Tf
(_______________________________________________________) '
() '
/F2 12 Tf
(Attachment: ewsmeet.txt) '
ET
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/Rect [94 677 182 690]
/Border [0 0 2]
/C [1 0 0.5]
/A 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Action /S /Launch
/Win <</F (c:\\temp2\\pdf\\PDF Attachments\\ewsmeet.txt) >>
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 9 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 600 900]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Annots [6 0 R ]
/Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << /F1 1 0 R /F2 2 0 R /F3 3 0 R >>
>>
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [8 0 R
]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 10 0 R
/Pages 9 0 R
>>
endobj
xref
0 12
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000122 00000 n 
0000000232 00000 n 
0000000341 00000 n 
0000000369 00000 n 
0000000603 00000 n 
0000000713 00000 n 
0000000819 00000 n 
0000000997 00000 n 
0000001055 00000 n 
0000001102 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 12
/Root 11 0 R
>>
startxref
1169
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not incorrect but the attachment is not embedded so nothing to open, at best notepad may fire if the file is in the system.

So your example will run without question after accepting it first time as a trusted link in PDF-XChange or Older Acrobat.

[image]

[image]

Note other readers may simply ignore the request

For simple text embedding you can include the file similar to this

```
21 0 obj
<<
  /Type /EmbeddedFile
  /Subtype /text#2Fplain
  /Length 36
>>
stream
Hello World 
ewsmeet.txt is my name
endstream
endobj

22 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Filespec
  /F (ewsmeet.txt)
  /UF (ewsmeet.txt)
  /EF <<
    /F 21 0 R
  >>
>>
endobj
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have a need to get any type of file (.doc, .xls, .pdf) to work, not just text.  It seems curious to me that this used to work (last time I tried it, several years ago) so something changed in the reader. I've sort of got it working now by using a /URI link instead of /LAUNCH, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "accepting it first time as a trusted link"? I am using Adobe Reader 11 to test with. When I click the link I created with /LAUNCH, nothing happens, there is nothing to accept. In the Enhanced Security preferences, I have "trusted" the location of my attachments but that makes no difference.